# Long \sqrt in two lines

Tags: equations

I want to rewrite the following equation in two line due to columnwidth of the article.

```
\begin{eqnarray}
y&=\pm &\sqrt{\frac{Q}{2\pi \sigma_y\sigma_z u C(x,y,z) } \exp{\left(\!-\frac{y^2}{2\sigma_y^2}\right)} \left[ \exp\!{\bigg(\!-\!\frac{\left(z-H\right)^2}{2\sigma_z^2}\!\bigg)}\right. \left.+ \exp\!{\bigg(\!-\!\frac{\left(z+H\right)^2}{2\sigma_z^2}\!\bigg)}\right]}\nonumber\\
\end{eqnarray}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Some suggestions

- [Don't use `eqnarray`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/197/5001) -- it's badly deprecated. If you need to align consecutive equations on some chosen marker (say, an `=` symbol), use the `align` environment of the `amsmath` package.
- The term `\exp` is a math operator and doesn't take an argument. Really.
- Don't over-use `\left` and `\right` to auto-size parentheses. Among other things, using `\left` and `\right` introduces extra white-space, which isn't desirable here, is it?
- Instead of `\bigg(\!-\!\frac...`, write `\biggl(-\frac...`. (And, use `\biggr)` instead of just `\bigg)`.) TeX's spacing rules treat `-` as a unary operator if it's preceded by an object to type `math-open`; `\biggl(` is such an object, whereas `\bigg(` is not.
- The equation is simply too wide to fit inside the text block, it has to be broken up into two lines. I suggest you use a `split` environment inside an `equation` environment for this purpose. And, use `\biggl\{` in the first row and `\biggr\}^{1/2}` in the second to denote the start and end of the material whose square root is being taken.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'split' environment
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
y&=\pm\biggl\{
   \frac{Q}{2\pi \sigma_y\sigma_z u C(x,y,z) } 
   \exp\biggl(-\frac{y^2}{2\sigma_y^2}\biggr) \\
 &\qquad\quad \times\biggl[ 
        \exp\biggl(-\frac{(z-H)^2}{2\sigma_z^2}\biggr)+ 
        \exp\biggl(-\frac{(z+H)^2}{2\sigma_z^2}\biggr)
  \biggr] 
  \biggr\}^{\!1/2}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Given the `twocolumn` constraint, `multline` is still an option:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'multline' environment
\begin{document}

And a multline equation ...
\begin{multline}
y=\pm\biggl\{
   \frac{Q}{2\pi \sigma_y\sigma_z u C(x,y,z) } 
   \exp\biggl(-\frac{y^2}{2\sigma_y^2}\biggr) \\
  \times\biggl[ 
        \exp\biggl(-\frac{(z-H)^2}{2\sigma_z^2}\biggr)+ 
        \exp\biggl(-\frac{(z+H)^2}{2\sigma_z^2}\biggr)
  \biggr] 
  \biggr\}^{\!1/2}
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure, actually, if the OP has indicated that the document is being typeset in two-column mode. All he/she has indicated, for sure, is that the equation, as posted, doesn't fit inside the given column. Let's see if the OP clarifies this issue. Aside: I'm glad to see my coding is so helpful... :-)

Comment: Sure, your code is nice ;-) - I suggested that for standard common paper sizes (letter or A4), the equation would fit anyway. So, I drew my assumption of `twocolumn`. OK, let's see if the OP clarifies this!

Comment: By the way, I'm always pleased if my code appears to be helpful.

Comment: Yes, the page format is twocolumn. Both of the answers are well fitted. In addition, I will follow the suggestions by Mico for other issues. :)

Comment: So, I deserve a (+1) for being smart, Hahaha.

Comment: @AboAmmar - +1. You definitely deserve such an upvote. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using `\delimitershortfall` for better heights of `({[]})`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

{\delimitershortfall=-1pt% hold it local
\begin{multline}
y =\pm\left\{
    \frac{Q}{2\pi \sigma_y\sigma_z u C(x,y,z) } 
      \exp\left(-\frac{y^2}{2\sigma_y^2}\right)\right. \\
    \times\left.\left[ 
       \exp\left(-\frac{(z-H)^2}{2\sigma_z^2}\right)+ 
       \exp\left(-\frac{(z+H)^2}{2\sigma_z^2}\right)
    \right] \right\}^{\!1/2}
    \end{multline}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The closing curly brace looks to be quite a bit larger than the opening curly brace on the preceding line.

Comment: yes, I forgot the `\vphantom{\left[...\right]}` for the first equation.